# Using lodash/set on a React.useState object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, set, lodash

when using React.useState, I can't mutate the object before using the setState method.

for example:

```
const [buffer, setBuffer] = React.useState(props.someObject);

function handleChange(field: string, data: someObject) {
 const update = lodash.set(buffer, field, data);
 setBuffer(update);
}
```

const update never gets the updated data at the path of field. If field is something like "path/path/value" just using setBuffer isn't simple without the help of lodash.set

I know I can do `const update = lodash.set(lodash.cloneDeep(buffer), field, data);` but that is expensive, especially when we're talking about handleChange being called on every user interaction with a form.

Any alternative approaches or insights into why updates on React.useState objects don't work is much appreciated!

Comment: They don't work when you mutate the existing object and shove it back in state. React state updates work by creating new object references for all the state being updated. Don't necessarily need a deep clone/copy, typically you only need a shallow copy of the parts of state that aren't being updated. If you could update your question to include an example `props.someObject` object we could help you apply the [Immutable Update pattern](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) to your state updates.

Comment: @DrewReese here's an example:

```
person: {
  firstName: "a name",
  phones: [{ number, typeId}]
  address: { line1, city, state},
}
```

Comment: @DrewReese that article is helpful, thank you. It helps me understand why lodash.set isn't working in the example above

Comment: You may also be interested in [immutable.js](https://immutable-js.com/) as well. It allows you to mutate a draft copy of the state like a normal sane developer, and then the draft is "committed" and changes applied immutably. Redux-toolkit uses it under the hood for example, so you don't need to do all the boilerplate shallow copying pattern of the Immutable Update Pattern from that first redux doc.